# Multiple screens In one slider view for android and firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I want to create the look shown in below image. Basically the user should go through all screens until he reaches the final screen.

[image: All screens]

I want to know if it is better to create a slider for this which can have all screens in it or to have a new activity for every page. I want to add all the inputs from these fields in the database in one single row (entry) instead of each item as one entry. I am using Firebase database to do so. Please let me know what would be a good option to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use activity option but in this case you have choose one two options: passing all previous values to the next activity and keeping data in a holder whose scope is longer than activity scope. The former option is better actually for this purpose but it is not recommended because it causes a key mess in your activities. I think the best approach is to use fragments for each screen and keeping the data in the parent activity.

Comment: Will I be able to switch between fragments by clicking the next button? I am sorry , I am new to android and this might be a silly question. How can I implement fragments for this?

Comment: You can take a look to the documentation. I recommends view pager2 https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view-2